# Why does "per" translate into devision in math?

Tags: notation

For example, when we want to represent speed, measured in meters per second, we are taught to write it as **m/s** , but why exactly do we divide meters (m) by seconds (s)?

Or, as for another example, in calculus, to represent a change of one quantity (call it "y") with respect to (or "per") another quantity (call it "x"), we write: **dy/dx** , or dy "divided by" dx. But, again, why division? What exactly is being "divided" here? How can I visualize this?

Comment: The speed units come from the equation of motion without acceleration $S=v\cdot t$. By the units you use for $S$ and $t$ you will get the units of $v=\frac{S}{t}$, this is the division. As for the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ it is just a good notation for the derivative, also known as Leibniz's notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Per" may be short for a "part of", "fraction of" , " pertaining to" or  " pertaining to units of" &c.

Sixty percent is 60 in fraction of 100, implying division as the needed operation here.

It may also be short for " for each" ;  60 kmph is 60 km for each hour, and since the total km distance is a multiple of 60, "per" denotes the opposite, in sense of division.

It may have originated from the Sankrit word *"prathi,"* meaning *each, every*..

Comment: The English *per*, in this context meaning “for each,” comes from Latin, with perhaps a detour through Old French. It certainly isn’t derived from Sanskrit, though the words are likely cognate.

Comment: "certainly" ?!.. In this forum its best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The term "per" in this context means "**for each**".

**EG** "10 m/s" means 10 m for each second